# What is wrong with this Bin to Dec script?

Tags: javascript

I am making a bin-to-dec script in JS (i know js has its own function to do it) as my homework, but it doesn't work - it returns the value as NaN. Can somebody explain what did I do wrong here?

```
function binToDec(bin){
    var x=bin.length;
    for (i=0; i<bin.length ; i++){
        var r=Math.pow(parseInt(bin.charAt(i),10)*2, x-1);
        x-=1;
        y+=r;   
    }
    return y;
}
var bin=prompt('input a bin number');
var y=binToDec(bin);
alert('this number in dec is: '+y);
```

Comment: `y` is neither declared nor initialized in your function.

Comment: best way to figure it out is break apart the line where you calculate `r` into its component parts and see what values are calculated at each step.

Comment: You are aware you can just do `var y = parseInt(bin, 2);`, right? ;-)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - thank you, I managed to make it work right now :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes I am, but the teacher wanted me to do a script for that, without using the existing functions

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `y` is not declared in your function, so what happens is you are effectively trying to add `r` to `undefined`, which results in `NaN`.

This seems to work:

```
function binToDec(bin){
    var x=bin.length;
    var y = -1;//Define y here
    for (i=0; i<bin.length ; i++){
        var r=Math.pow(parseInt(bin.charAt(i),10)*2, x-1);
        x-=1;
        y+=r;   
    }
    return y;
}
var bin=prompt('input a bin number');
var y=binToDec(bin);
alert('this number in dec is: '+y);
```

Notice that `y` is set to `-1` by default, as your result always seemed to be 1 more than it should be when I tried `0` (I haven't read fully into your logic to know the exact reason, I just know you need to account for it)

Comment: As for me, setting the y to 0 is perfect, i don't know why do you think it's 1 too high. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Garewin: When I test it I got the wrong results. I used [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQBP7/) in Chrome. Actually, on 2nd look , the results are very different... `0001` = 1, but `0010` = 3

Comment: Whoa. Didn't realise that, added a `if (bin.charAt(bin.length-1)==0){
 y-=1;
 }` and now it works perfectly.